# How to monitor embedded Flume agent?

Tags: java, flume, threadpoolexecutor, flume-ng

I use embedded Flume agent in my code to send data to sinks.
I use a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to start a Runnable class where I configure, start and put events into Agent.

How do I know if the transfer was successful or not?
I need a trigger in case of failure to process the data differently.

There seems not to be any more control than configure, start, put, stop.

For example, I get:

> [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-LoadBalancingSinkProcessor] ERROR
>   org.apache.flume.SinkRunner:160  - Unable to deliver event. Exception
>   follows. 
>       org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: All configured sinks have failed

But how can I catch that? And if I stop the agent how do I access jobs/events that have failed to send?